# Parameterizable FIFO with multiple inputs and outputs?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hardware, synthesis

I want to create a FIFO with multiple & parameterizable number of inputs and outputs. Saying as soon as there are enough data, the FIFO will pump them out. In my use case, I have 4 inputs and outputs, something like this:

```
input  [7:0] din1, din2, din3, din4;
input  [3:0] din_valid;
output [7:0] dout1, dout2, dout3, dout4;
output       dout_valid;
```

With examples:

```
din*       = 0,1,2,3 -> 4,5,6,7 -> 8,9,0,1
din_valid  = 4'b0011 -> 4'b1101 -> 4'b1110
dout       = x,x,x,x -> x,x,x,x -> 2,3,4,5 -> 7,8,9,0 -> x,x,x,x
dout_valid = 1'b0    -> 1'b0    -> 1'b1    -> 1'b1    -> 1'b0
```

I have been able to make this working by having like a fixed size memory registers, and shifting the data in manually with case statements for `din_valid` (0000, 0001, etc.).

However, this seems to be very inefficient if the number of outputs increases, to like 6 or 8. I can have a read & write pointers as in normal FIFO to traverse the memory accordingly; however, the problem arises when the value of read & write pointers overflow, and additional "wrapping around" logic is super complicated since we are not increasing them by just 1.

Are there any other methods to create a multi-input, multi-output FIFO, with the "memory shifting" logic being parameterizable (in this case we will just make *din1, din2...* a single *[NUM_INPUTxBIT-1:0]din*) ? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this would mean we need additional logic to assign value to each of the FIFO right? In case only 3/4 data is valid, we will have to assign data to 3 FIFOs and leaves the last one by itself, then also a pointer pointing to that FIFO to tell the first data of the next cycle to go there instead.

Comment: which is not much difference than having them all in 1 module. I guess it is not just FIFO, but more of like FIFO with aligned output.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any other methods to create a multi-input, multi-output
> FIFO, being parameterizable ... ?

Yes, you can use unpacked array ports as well:

```
module fifo #(parameter N=4) (
    input  [N-1:0] din_valid,
    input  [7:0]   din  [N],
    output [7:0]   dout [N]
);

endmodule
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 7.4.2 *Unpacked arrays*.

Comment: Hi toolic, thanks for the information, however the "parameterizable" I am looking for is more for the "shifter" logic of the memory block. For example, if din[0], din[2], din[3] is valid and din[1] is not, we need to somehow allocate them to memory block [2], [1], [0] manually. However I want to make it generic, since with four inputs there are already 16 cases to check for din_valid, more than that would be inefficient. (Btw, the remaining memory can be shifted with a generate easily so I won't mention it here). I kinda feel like this is not be possible now, but would love to hear some ideas.